# Cucumber - Scenario outline - When i use scenario out line for data parameterization , after run it throws an error and all steps are skipped

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Below is the Cucumber Scenario in which steps 1,2,4,5,6 are working fine as it picks from other feature 
 file but then 3 and 7 step is giving an problem.

```
@Api
  Scenario Outline: Getting Primary category count from Solr
    Given User should have the base url for search vehicle
    When User passes items per page as "20"
    And User passes facet region as "US" and primarycategory type as "<Primary Category>"
    And User fetches records with  "/api/vehicles" endpoint
    Then User should get status code "200" in response
    And User should get 20 vehicles records in the response
    Then User should get "<Primary Category>" count as  "<Category Count>" in the response

    Examples: 
      | Primary Category | Category Count |
      | truck            |           2125 |
      | Tractor          |           2366 |
      | Trailer          |            530 |
      | Specialized      |              0 |
      | Reclassified     |              0 |
```

Below is my code

```
@And("^User passes facet region as \"([^\"]*)\" and primarycategory type as \"([^\"]*)\" $")
    public void user_passes_facet_region_as_and_primarycategory_type_as(String region, String primary_category) {
        httpRequest.queryParam("facets", "r="+region+";g="+primary_category).urlEncodingEnabled(true);
    }

    @Then("User should get \"([^\"]*)\" count as  \"([^\"]*)\" in the response$")
    public void user_should_get_primary_category_count_as_in_the_response(int int1) {

      int  cat_count = response.jsonPath().get("Data.Count");

      Assert.assertEquals(cat_count,int1);
    }

After run i am getting the below error on console 
 @Api
  Scenario Outline: Getting Primary category count from Solr                 # featurefile/PrimaryCategoryCount_From_Solr_API.feature:16
    Given User should have the base url for search vehicle                   # FacetsSearchAPISteps.user_should_have_the_base_url_for_search_vehicle()
    When User passes items per page as "20"                                  # FacetsSearchAPISteps.user_passes_items_per_page_as(String)
    And User passes facet region as "US" and primarycategory type as "truck" # null
    And User fectches records with  "/api/vehicles" endpoint                 # FacetsSearchAPISteps.user_fectches_records_with_endpoint(String)
    Then User should get status code "200" in response                       # FacetsSearchAPISteps.i_should_get_status_code_in_response(String)
    And User should get 20 vehicles records in the response                  # FacetsSearchAPISteps.user_should_get_vehicles_records_in_the_response(int)
    Then User should get "truck" count as  "2125" in the response            # PrimaryCategoryCount_From_Solr_API_Steps.user_should_get_primary_category_count_as_in_the_response(int)
```

I dont know where is the issue can somebody help me.

Comment: add the error you are geeting

Comment: What do you mean by "picks from another feature file"?